# How to send messages from telegram API using a python script? (NO bots/tokens)

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

How to send messages from telegram API using a python script? (NO bots/tokens)

Hello, I was trying to create a python program to automatically forward the messages that arrive to a chat between me and my friend1, to another chat between me and my friend2.

The problem I have is that the script does not present any errors during execution, however, after the login process the script does nothing. That is, it does not detect my friend1's messages and therefore does not send them to my friend2.

I haven't found much information on how to do it, I always find programs that interact with bots.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 'MY_API_ID' #number
api_hash = 'MY_API_HASH' #long alphanumeric
phone = 'MY_PHONE-NUMBER'#+123456789

CHAT_ID = 'FRIEND_CHAT_ID' #number
CHAT_ID2 = 'FRIEND2_CHAT_ID' #number

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.chat_id == CHAT_ID:
        await client.send_message(CHAT_ID2, event.text)

async def main():
    await client.start(phone)
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```